# In an employee table, if manager id and employee id is same, then get the manager names for employee

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

I have tried to do inner join. But I have to show the result using SQL procedure
I have tried using inner join but I am expecting procedure

Comment: If manager ID and employee ID are the same, it means that I'm my own manager. Anyway: could you post some sample data and expected result? I don't quite understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> In an employee table, if manager id and employee id is same, then get the manager names for employee

If the `id` for the employee is the same as the `id` from the manager and each Employee has a unique `id` then the name of the manager is the name of the employee and you can use:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   employee
WHERE  employee_id = manager_id;
```